# How do I store my pictures on the internet and how do I pull them into my app?

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, storage

I am making an application in Flutter and I have thousands of images and I don't want to add them one by one to the pubspeck.yaml file, there should definitely be a way to store the images and pull them with url path. But I don't know how to do this, I tried it with google photos before but it couldn't display it (I guess I didn't use it correctly). Do you have any idea about this subject? waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of different approaches to achieve this if you want you can always add a whole directory in your pubspec.yaml file like this

```
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

If you want to use a database you could try firebase storgage, its free and very easy to implement in your app. See [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and [Init firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)